# Grothendieck category with a generator has injective hulls (envelopes): a subtlety in Freyd's book on abelian category

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

First, Freyd proves that an object in a Grothendieck category is injective if and only if it has no proper essential extensions. For each object $A$ of the category, he chooses a monomorphism $e_A\colon A\to E(A)$ which is the identity if $A$ is injective, and a proper essential extension otherwise. Then, by transfinite recursion, Freyd defines, for an object $A$, $E^0(A) = A, E^{\alpha + 1}(A) = E(E^{\alpha}(A))$ and, for a limit ordinal $\gamma, E^{\gamma}(A)$ to be a minimal essential extension of $A$ which bounds $E^{\alpha}(A)$ for all $\alpha < \gamma$ (the validity of this construct is also proved).

For a generator $G$ of the Grothendieck category $\mathsf{A}$, he considers a functor $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,-)$ which is a faithful left exact functor into the category of $R$-modules ($R=\mathsf{End_A}(G)$). Then it is a proven that if the extension $u\colon A\to E$ is essential, so is $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u)\colon \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,A)\to\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E)$.

Finally, using the fact that $R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ has enough injectives, there is a monomorphism $q\colon\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,A)\to Q$ into an injective $R$-module. For any essential extension $u\colon A\to E$, $q$ then factors as $h_u\circ\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u)$ where $h_u$ is monic as $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u)$ is essential (this a property of essential extensions).

The idea is the there are no more essential extensions of $A$ than there are subobjects of $Q$ which form a set was $\mathsf{A}$ is well-powered. However, I don't see why it is true. The book claims that that this is due to $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,-)$ being faithful. The way I understand this:

> The induced map from the set of essential extensions of $A$ to the set of essential extensions of $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,A)$ is injective. However, this naive ideal doesn't take into account the fact that we work with equivalence classes (subobjects are equivalence classes). Indeed, the map on equivalence classes doesn't have to be injective as $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,-)$ doesn't have to be full. Let $u,v$ be essential extensions of $A$ such that $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u)$ and $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,v)$ are equivalent as extensions of $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,A)$. Then there is an $R$-module isomorphism $\rho$ such that $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u) = \rho\circ\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,v)$. But $\rho$ is not necessarily an image of a morphism in $\mathsf{A}$.

> The induced map from the set of essential extensions of $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,A)$ into the set of subobjects of $Q$ is injective. I don't see that it is well-defined. Indeed, if $x,y$ are equivalent extensions of $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u)$, then there is an isomorphism $z$ such that $x = z\circ y$. Let $h_x$ and $h_y$ be respective lifts. Then $h_x\circ z\circ y = h_y\circ y$, but not necessarily $h_x\circ z = h_y$ as $y$ is not necessarily epic.

Comment: Is $G$ assumed to be a *compact* generator or just a generator ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Just a (strong) generator.

Comment: What's "strong" in "strong generator" ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi That's what some people call it to distinguish it from another notion of generator, which is common in the theory of trinangulated categories. For the sake of this question, a generator is an object $G$ such that for any $f,f'\colon A\to B$ with $f \neq g$ there is a morphism $g\colon G\to A$ such that $f\circ g \neq f'\circ g$.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Do you think there is a mistake in the book?

Comment: OK - no I don't specifically think so, I haven't had the time to really think about it. The reason I asked is that if $G$ is in fact compact, it's pretty easy to answer the first of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the proof isn't really that there are no more essential extensions of $A$ than subobjects of $Q$, but that the length of a chain of proper essential extensions of $A$ is at most the length of a chain of proper inclusions of subobjects of $Q$.

Suppose $\{E_\alpha\mid \alpha<\beta\}$ is a chain of objects of $\mathsf{A}$ indexed by an ordinal $\beta$, with $E_0=A$ and $E_\alpha<E_{\alpha'}$ a proper essential extension for $\alpha<\alpha'$. Then Freyd explicitly proves that $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\alpha)<\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha'})$ is an essential extension of $R$-modules. But also it is a proper extension, since
$$0\to\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\alpha)\to\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha'})\to\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha'}/E_\alpha)$$
is exact, and $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha'}/E_\alpha)\neq0$ since $E_{\alpha'}/E_\alpha\neq0$ and $G$ is a generator.

Comment: Nice one, thanks a lot!

Comment: However, what about $q_{\alpha}\colon \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha})\to Q$ making $q_{\alpha}\circ \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u) =  q$ for $u\colon A\to E_{\alpha}$ for limit ordinal $\alpha?$ In order to $q_{\alpha}$ to be a proper subobject of $q_{\alpha'}$ for $\alpha' < \alpha$, we need to define these by transfinite recursion starting for $\alpha = 0$ (otherwise these aren't necessarily proper inclusions). Generally, a an infinite union is defined as an image of the morphism induced by the infinite direct sum, but these are not necessarily preserved by $\mathsf{Hom}$-functors. What to do here?

Comment: Hmm, it appears we can, for a limit ordinal, take the intersection of a chain of proper subobjects of $Q$ to obtain another proper subobject of $Q$. For the transition from $\alpha$ to $\alpha + 1$, we use the proper extension $E_{\alpha} < E_{\alpha + 1}$ to obtain a proper subobject $E_{\alpha + 1} \to Q$ of $E_{\alpha} \to Q$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Jxt921 The (underlying objects of the) subobjects of $Q$ are just the objects $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\alpha)$; you don't need to take unions or intersections to construct them. But to construct the monomorphisms to $Q$, for a limit ordinal $\alpha$, the monomorphisms $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\beta)\to Q$, for $\beta<\alpha$, induce a monomorphism $\text{colim}_{\beta<\alpha}\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\beta)\to Q$, and since $\text{colim}_{\beta<\alpha}\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\beta)$ embeds in $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\alpha)$ and $Q$ is injective, this extends to a map $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_\alpha)\to Q$.

Comment: But why $\mathrm{colim}_{\beta < \alpha} \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\beta})$ embeds into $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha})$? By the universal property of the colimit, there is a unique morphism $\mathrm{colim}_{\beta < \alpha} \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\beta}) \to \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha})$ such that $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\beta}) \to \mathrm{colim}_{\beta < \alpha} \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\beta}) \to \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\alpha})$ equals $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\beta}) \to \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\beta})$, but it doesn't have to be a monomorphism.

Comment: And a similar question about $\mathrm{colim}_{\beta < \alpha} \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E_{\beta}) \to Q$.

Comment: @Jxt921We're working in a module category (actually, AB5 is all that matters), so a directed colimit of monomorphisms is a monomorphism.

Comment: Dear professor Rickard, you've helped me in the past and I understand that you are one of the few specialist in triangulated categories. So, if you have time, please, have a look at this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/380935/83143